# Check First Char In String

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, char

I have input-box. I'm looking for a way to fire-up `alert()` if first character of given string is equal to '/'...

```
var scream = $( '#screameria input' ).val();

if ( scream.charAt( 0 ) == '/' ) {

  alert( 'Boom!' );

}
```

It's my code at the moment. It doesn't work and I think that it's because that browser doesn't know when to check that string... I need that alert whenever user inputs '/' as first character.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this out:

```
$( '#screameria input' ).keyup(function(){ //when a user types in input box
    var scream = this.value;
    if ( scream.charAt( 0 ) == '/' ) {

      alert( 'Boom!' );

    }
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FewgY/

Comment: There are one unexpected bug. When `alert()` is fired-up, user will try to close it with "Enter", but that will call `alert()` again. How would you solve this?

Comment: well what you can do is clear out the value before the `Boom` so they submit nothing: `this.value = ''`

Comment: @daGrevis -- #1 use jsFiddle. #2, the `isFired` variable is not in the global scope

Comment: @Neal But I use it only in that anonymous function... so does it matters? P.S. I will use jsFiddle. ;)

Comment: yes it only exists in that anon. and never at any other point. it disappears. -- poof --

Comment: Even "var" remove from `isFired` didn't help me (I try to make variable go in global scope)! I'm really sad now.

Comment: Use the jQuery `data` value: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/FewgY/4/  notice how in each input, it alerts `Boom` once

Comment: @daGrevis changed my fiddle link in the comment above

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a keypress (or similar) handler to tell the browser to run your function whenever a key is pressed on that input field:

```
var input = $('#screameria input');
input.keypress(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  if (val && val.charAt(0) == '/') {
    alert('Boom!');
  }
});
```

Comment: Do not use `input.val()`, use either `$(this).val()` or `this.value`, you have no idea how many inputs there are.

Comment: @Neal, ha, true.  I guess that's a sign that we're doing it right =)