# Check a certain section of string if it contains a substring

Tags: javascript, string

I want to check a certain section of my string if it contains a substring.

This is my code so far:

```
var sHexValue = document.getElementById("ColourInput").value;
fnDebugMessage(sHexValue);

if (sHexValue.includes("#", 0)) {
  fnDebugMessage("TRUE");
}
```

So currently it checks the `ColourInput` if it contains `#` from the position `0` in the string, however I want to restrict it so it checks only the first character of `ColourInput`

How do I do this?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: so you want to check if the first character in `sHexValue` is a `#`? You can do: `sHexValue[0] === "#"` if that's the case

Comment: You can check the characters in a string in a similar manner to an array. I.e, `sHexValue[0] === '#'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get first character of string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427132/how-to-get-first-character-of-string) and [Check First Char In String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348325) and [How to get first letter from string using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887742)

Comment: you only want to check the first character though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternate, using [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

```
document.getElementById("ColourInput").value.startsWith('#')
```

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't know there is actually a command to check if a string starts with a character

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get first element:

```
 document.getElementById("ColourInput").value.charAt(0) === "#"
```

This will check only the first character of the value if it is '#' which is what you are looking for, if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Try regexp

```
/^#/.test(sHexValue)
```

for full hex color use this

```
/^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/
```

```js
function check() {
  let sHexValue = document.getElementById("ColourInput").value;
  let msg="Not contains: #";

  if(/^#/.test(sHexValue)) msg="contains: #";

  console.log(msg);

  if(/^#[A-Fa-f0-9]{6}$/.test(sHexValue)) console.log("Color :)");
}
```

```html
<input id="ColourInput" onkeyup="check()">
```

Comment: Well this it will return true in position of #.

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way, check index of '#' char is 0.   Well this will work in case of multiple # characters as we are checking for 0th index.

```
 document.getElementById("ColourInput").value.indexOf('#') === 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to check if the index of char in string is 0.

```
sHexValue.indexOf("#") === 0
```

**Note :** includes() method may not be supported in IE browser. so just check with this method and let me know if you face after this.
Thanks.